# How to mock system.getenv

Tags: mockito

I have code which uses system.getenv() variables as below:

```
  String dbId = System.getenv("DB_ID");
  String clusterId = System.getenv("CLUSTER_ID");
```

I need to unit test it using Mockito. I can't use powermockito. How can I do?Any pointers??

Comment: That is a very old debate with plenty of answers/questions all over the web.

TLDR version is -> no you cannot do that as it is with only Mockito, usually people suggest you change your design and move static method in something you can actually mock. Or do not test it at all.

Alternatively - you may want to write a higher level test - set up actual environment variables so you do not need to mock.

I do not know which option is best for you, pick carefully :)

Comment: Thank you. For now I have abstracted static methods so I can test my logic.

Comment: Sounds good! This may also be a better design - taking out the responsibility to read system environment variables from the place you actually use them in your business logic.